# Composer/Symfony: dependency issues

Tags: symfony, composer-php, orocrm, platform.sh

### Context

I'm currently working on an OroPlatform project, which is based on Symfony 4.4 and deployed on [Platform.sh](https://platform.sh/).

I'm facing the following issue during the build phase of the deployment:

- My app needs the package `symfony/process` 4.4.X
- I don't know why, but on the Platform.sh server my app uses the `symfony/process` package installed for the composer binary installed globally, but this one is a 5.X version
- So, I've got an error and I can't install my app because it uses the 5.X version instead of the 4.X
- That's why I've found a workaround by using Composer 1.9.3 because it uses `symfony/process` 4.4.X, the same used by my app.

It was working well, but yesterday I have to bump the composer version to latest 1.X due to the Github OAuth token changes: https://nono.ma/github-oauth-token-for-github-com-contains-invalid-characters-on-composer-install

### Issue

So, I'm still facing this issue with the 4.X version and the 5.X version.

I've tried to install the dependencies of my project this way : `composer install -n -o -a` but the bug still occurs.

I'm looking for a way to force my project to use the dependencies located in the `vendor` folder of my app and not the ones installed globally. Here is a screenshot of the issue on the Platform.sh server:

[image]

And here is a schema of the path of my app and composer on a Platform.sh server:

```
/app
|
|__/vendor/symfony-process
|
|__/.global/vendor/symfony-process
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "oro/platform-application",
    "description": "Oro Platform Empty Application",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/oroinc/platform-application.git",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "src/AppKernel.php",
            "src/AppCache.php",
            "vendor/oro/platform/guzzle/Client.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Client.php",
            "**/Tests/"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": {
        "composer": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.orocrm.com"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.3.13 || ~7.4.2",
        "oro/platform": "4.1.*",
        "oro/platform-serialised-fields": "4.1.*",
        "oro/oauth2-server": "4.1.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat": "3.4.*",
        "behat/gherkin": "4.6.0",
        "behat/mink": "dev-master#6d637f7af4816c26ad8a943da2e3f7eef1231bea",
        "behat/mink-extension": "2.3.*",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.3.1",
        "behat/symfony2-extension": "2.1.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0.0",
        "nelmio/alice": "3.6.*",
        "theofidry/alice-data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "7.5.*",
        "johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap": "3.0.*",
        "mybuilder/phpunit-accelerator": "dev-master",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.5.*",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "2.6.*",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "4.0.*",
        "phpunit/phpcov": "5.0.*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "4.4.*",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "2.16.*",
        "oro/twig-inspector": "1.0.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "public/bundles/components",
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@build-parameters",
            "@set-permissions",
            "@install-assets",
            "@set-assets-version"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@build-parameters",
            "@set-permissions",
            "@update-assets",
            "@set-assets-version"
        ],
        "build-parameters": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
        ],
        "set-permissions": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setPermissions"
        ],
        "install-assets": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets"
        ],
        "update-assets": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::updateAssets"
        ],
        "set-assets-version": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion"
        ],
        "set-parameters": [
            "Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Composer\\ParametersHandler::set"
        ]
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "require": "4.4.*"
        },
        "symfony-web-dir": "public",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. How do you install the dependencies? When deploying `composer.lock`, the dependencies should not change

Comment: As I said in my post, with the following command line : `composer install -n -o -a`.
Exactly, as you can see on the screenshot, my Symfony/OroPlatform app load the `symfony/console` package required by composer instead of the one located into the `vendor` folder..

Comment: Could you share the content of the `composer.json` file? It may help a bit.

Comment: Added to the post @Leroy

Comment: "my Symfony/OroPlatform app load the symfony/console package required by composer instead of the one located into the vendor folder" - what does that mean? How does your deployment look like? Where does this `.global/vendor` folder come from? How does the configuration for your autoloader look like?

Comment: As you note, you have two versions of `symfony/process`, one installed by your application in `vendor` and one installed via pulling composer in `.global/vendor`. The question is why is the wrong one used. What is that `Fatal error` screenshot a screenshot of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've supposed that installing composer under the same folder as the web application don't seems to be a good practise. Moreover, it seems that Platform.sh don't use the composer binary.

So, I have change the build phase inside my `.platform.app.yaml` to avoid the way Platform.sh install Composer and use a custom way to do it:

```yaml
# .platform.app.yaml
hooks:
  build: |
    set -e
    cd $PLATFORM_APP_DIR

    # install Composer
    chmod +x composer-install.sh
    ./composer-install.sh
```

```sh
# composer-install.sh

#!/bin/sh

EXPECTED_CHECKSUM="$(php -r 'copy("https://composer.github.io/installer.sig", "php://stdout");')"
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ACTUAL_CHECKSUM="$(php -r "echo hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php');")"

if [ "$EXPECTED_CHECKSUM" != "$ACTUAL_CHECKSUM" ]
then
    >&2 echo 'ERROR: Invalid installer checksum'
    rm composer-setup.php
    exit 1
fi

php composer-setup.php --1 --quiet
RESULT=$?
rm composer-setup.php
>&1 echo 'Composer successfully installed'
exit $RESULT
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing the package, so it will be added to your composer.json file.

```sh
composer install symfony/process
```

The following section will cause the correct version to be installed

```json
"extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "require": "4.4.*"
        },
```

Once you've run the command, the package should be added as follows :

```
"symfony/process": "4.4.*"
```

If it does not, change it to that version number and run

```
composer update symfony/process
```

Comment: Thanks @Leroy, I have already tried to do that, but as you can see on the screenshot of my post, my Symfony app load the `symfony/process` class loaded into `/app/.global/vendor` instead of the one located into `/app/vendor`..

Comment: Did you run that after the application was deployed, or on your local machine before deploying it? Because that command should add it to the `composer.json`. I don't know platform.sh, but maybe they will consider all post deployment installations as globally installed packages.